# Convert QString hexadecimal to ASCII value

Tags: c++, qt, hex, qstring

My goal is **to convert an hexadecimal value which is contained in a QString to its ASCII value**.

I have :

```
QString hexaValue = receiveText.left(14); // receive texte is another QString
```

My problem here, is that I have my hexadecimal value in a `Qstring` and not in a `QByteArray`, so all of the solutions that I found are not working, I try to call `.data()` or `fromHex()` , but this ain't working here, because I'm forced to used a `QString` and not a `QByteArray`

Should I convert my `QString` to a `QByteArray`, is there a simple solution ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just use `QString::toLatin1`to convert hex string to QByteArray and to convert it back to QString use either `QString::fromLocal8Bit` for local encoding or `QString::fromUtf8` if your hex encoded string are in UTF8.

```
QString hexaValue = receiveText.left(14); // received text is another QString
QString textValue = QString::fromLocal8Bit(QByteArray::fromHex(hexaValue.toLatin1()));
```